# Understanding Python class instantiation

Tags: python, subclass

Trying to figure out class inheritance of class attributes that are themselves classes. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
class foo:
    hello = None
    world = None

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for k,v in kwargs.items():
            if hasattr(self, k):
                setattr(self, k, v)
            else:
                raise AttributeError(f'class foo has no attribute {k}')


class foo2:
    hi = None
    earth = None

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for k,v in kwargs.items():
            if hasattr(self, k):
                setattr(self, k, v)
            else:
                raise AttributeError(f'class foo has no attribute {k}')

class bar:
    foo_attr = foo(hello=1, world=2)
    foo2_attr = foo2(hi=3, earth=4)


class bar2(bar):
    def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
```

So I have 2 base classes (`foo and foo2`) with 2 attributes each (`hello` & `world`, `hi` & `earth`, respectively).

I have another base class (`bar`) that has class attributes inside with default values for `foo` and `foo2`.

**Update (to include question):**

Lastly, I have `bar2` which is a subclass of `bar`. How can I change the values of an attribute of a subclass that are themselves, classes? (say hello attribute of the foo_attr in bar2)

I'm trying to set a default value for `bar` but i want to be able to set different attributes for each of the class attributes inside bar when I subclass it. This way, I can create a bunch of subclasses of bar like so:

a `bar2` with default attributes except foo2.earth which i set to 20. So that means bar2 has:

- foo.hello = 1
- foo.world = 2
- foo2.hi = 3
- foo2.earth = 20

and then still be able to create a bar3, with say default attributes for foo() and foo2() except for foo.hello, which maybe I want to set to 30 and then add a new attribute of say "jeez".

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: what is the question

Comment: "How can I change the values of an attribute of a subclass that are themselves, classes" they are not classes...

Comment: sorry, is the correct term, instance of classes?

I'm still trying to learn all the proper terms to be used when asking a question. My bad!

Comment: Yes, they are instances of a class. But *everything* in Python is an instance of a class, even classes themselves. That's why you hear "everything is an object in Python". Anyway, can't you just do `foo2_attr = foo2(hi=3, earth=20)` in `bar2`? btw, I dig the black zero avatar.

Comment: yes, technically I could -- but my issue here is: the actual classes I'm making have around 10 + attributes of the same class. If say I have a bar class with 10 different foo_attr (i.e. foo1_attr, foo2_attr, ..., foo10_attr) and I wante to change all of the hello attributes of each foo{x}_attr to say 1,2,3,...,8,9,10, I could technically just assign everything again. I'm, hopefully, looking to find a DRY method to do this over many bar subclasses.

Comment: In your example, you mean `bar2.foo_attr.hello  = 1` and etc... (that is, using the class attribute names from bar?)

Comment: @tdelaney, something like I want to set just `bar2.foo2_attr.earth = 20` but have all the other be default values inherited from bar.

Comment: You need to make a copy of `foo` to get whatever values are set by default on `bar.foo_attr` and then update it with any new values you want instead. This could be expressed on `foo` itself (a new method) or in a shared super class to foo and foo2 so you don't duplicate, or perhaps a static factory object.

Comment: As an aside, your class attribute thing is more complicated than python's default arguments (e.g., `def __init__(self, hello=None, world=None)`. I assume you need to do it the more complicated way?

Comment: @tdelaney yes. At first, the way I set the values for bar2 is hardcoded (something similar to what @juanpa.arrivillaga suggested). But it was getting too tedious now that I have to make, something like, 6 different subclasses of bar all of them with different attributes not in another subclass, but each of them having shared attributes of a class instance (`foo` and `foo2`)  but with differing `hello`s and `hi`s.

Comment: Okay, however _each of them having shared attributes of a class instance (foo and foo2) but ..._ - that's one big _but_. They are not shared objects, you need different instances if they are to have different attribute values.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to create an explicit constructor for `bar` and `bar2` so that you can choose the attributes:

```
class bar:
    def __init__(self, hello=1, world=2, hi=3, earth=4)
        self.foo_attr = foo(hello=hello, world=world)
        self.foo2_attr = foo2(hi=hi, earth=earth)

class bar2:
    def __init__(self)
        bar.__init__(self, earth=20)
```

You can still add new attributes in the new classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put the functionality into `foo` and `foo2` and you have less duplication if those inherit from a common super class with the functionality. The below script works (I had to remove the 'f' strings because I'm mired in the dark old days of python 3.5). There is still some work implementing the bar subclasses, but relatively sane.

```
import copy

class Fooinator:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        badniks = self._update_instance(**kwargs)
        if badniks:
            raise AttributeError('class foo has no attributes {}'.format(badniks))

    def _update_instance(self, **kwargs):
        """Update self for variables defined at the class level returning
        names of variables not used by this class. """
        badniks = []
        for k,v in kwargs.items():
            if hasattr(self, k):
                setattr(self, k, v)
            else:
                badniks.append(k)
        return badniks

    def opt_clone(self, **kwargs):
        """Given keyword arguments, clone a copy of self if any of them are
        used by this class, else return self."""
        for k in kwargs:
            if hasattr(self, k):
                me_2 = copy.copy(self)
                me_2._update_instance(**kwargs)
                return me_2
        return self


class foo(Fooinator):
    hello = None
    world = None


class foo2(Fooinator):
    hi = None
    earth = None


class bar:
    foo_attr = foo(hello=1, world=2)
    foo2_attr = foo2(hi=3, earth=4)


class bar2(bar):
    foo2_attr = bar.foo2_attr.opt_clone(earth=20)

b = bar2()
print(b.foo_attr.hello, b.foo_attr.world, b.foo2_attr.hi, b.foo2_attr.earth)
```